# Unity Raycast() and DrawRay() creates different Rays using same inputs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to create a curved Ray and need to list the object that curved Ray hits. I am able to draw a curved Ray with Debug.DrawRay(). However, When I provide Raycast() the same parameters with DrawRay(), It's creating very different Ray (I guess because I can't see the Ray). The Raycast()'s Ray hits the object I highlighted in the image. But DrawRay()'s Ray is too far to hit the highlighted object. How can I make them create identical Rays? 
[image: Here you can see the difference]

```
//Here is the code:

public void CurveCast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, Vector3 gravityDirection, int smoothness, float maxDistance, float direction_multiply, float radius)
{
    Vector3 currPos = origin, hypoPos = origin, hypoVel = (direction.normalized / smoothness) * direction_multiply;
    List<Vector3> v = new List<Vector3>();        
    float curveCastLength = 0;

    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;
    hit_list = new List<RaycastHit>();
    while (curveCastLength < maxDistance)
    {
        ray = new Ray(currPos, hypoVel);

        Debug.DrawRay(currPos, hypoVel, Color.white);
        if (Physics.Raycast(currPos, hypoVel, out hit)) // if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, radius, out hit,maxDistance))
        {
            hit_list.Add(hit);
        }


        v.Add(hypoPos);
        currPos = hypoPos;
        hypoPos = currPos + hypoVel + (gravityDirection * Time.fixedDeltaTime / (smoothness * smoothness));
        hypoVel = hypoPos - currPos;
        curveCastLength += hypoVel.magnitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. I saw in your profile that you never accepted an answer. Accepting and answer help sorting which questions are closed. Here is a link to stack overflow guideline about that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `Debug.DrawRay` and `Physics.Raycast` are not exactly the same.

In `Debug.DrawRay`, the length of the ray is defined by the vector magnitude. You can [see it in the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html):

> Draws a line from start to start + dir in world coordinates.

For `Physics.Raycast`, the length of the ray is independant from the direction and can be set as a parameter. Its default value is infinite, so if you don't define it, the raycast will go to infinity, even if the direction vector is short. [See the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html):

> Casts a ray, from point origin, in direction direction, of length maxDistance, against all colliders in the scene.

So the solution for you is to give the proper distance to the Raycast function:

```
Debug.DrawRay(currPos, hypoVel, Color.white);
if (Physics.Raycast(currPos, hypoVel, out hit, hypoVel.magnitude())) // if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, radius, out hit,maxDistance))
{
    hit_list.Add(hit);
}
```

Comment: the correct version is this one: Physics.Raycast(currPos, hypoVel, out hit, hypoVel.magnitude )) . However, it worked ! Thanks so much.